# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "(double, double)" в "float"

Tags: c#

```
case Jumps.Dancify:
{
    Vector2 centre = (lastPosition + targetPosition) / 2f;
    float cursor;
    double rotate = 180.0;
    float num = (float)Cursor.Position.X;
    float num2 = (float)Cursor.Position.Y;
    num = (num + 170f) / 512f;
    num2 = (num2 + 55f) / 384f;      
    double num9 = Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((double)(num), 2.0) + Math.Pow((double)(num2), 2.0)) / 2.0);
    float chrnum2 = 1f;
    int chrnum1 = (int)num + (int)(num) / 2;
    int num14 = (int)num2 + (int)(num2) / 2;
    double num15 = (Math.Atan2((double)num2, 0.0) - Math.Atan2((double)(num2), (double)(num))) * 180.0 / 3.1415926535897931 + 90.0;
    double idk = Math.Abs((float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((double)(num), 2.0) + Math.Pow((double)(num2), 2.0)) / 2.0);
    cursor = (num13 + ((float)num9 * Math.Cos((rotate * chrnum2 - num15) / 180.0 * (float)3.1415926535897931)), num14 - ((float)num9 * Math.Sin((rotate * num12 - num15 + 180.0) / 180.0 * (float)3.1415926535897931)));
    for (float num16 = lastFrame.time + frameDelay; num16 < h.StartTime; num16 += frameDelay)
    {
        Vector2 vector6 = flag ? OsuMathHelper.CirclePoint(centre, cursor, OsuMathHelper.CircleTAt(lastPosition, centre) + ((num12 - num16) / (num13 / 3.14159274f))) : OsuMathHelper.CirclePoint(centre, cursor, OsuMathHelper.CircleTAt(lastPosition, centre) + (double)((num16 - num12) / (num13 / 3.14159274f)));
        RulesetOsu.AddFrameToReplay(replay, new bReplayFrame((int)num16, vector6.X, vector6.Y, lastFrame.buttonState));
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: | эта строчка выдает ошибку|
cursor = (num13 + ((float)num9 * Math.Cos((rotate * chrnum2 - num15) / 180.0 * (float)3.1415926535897931)), num14 - ((float)num9 * Math.Sin((rotate * num12 - num15 + 180.0) / 180.0 * (float)3.1415926535897931)));

Comment: что происходит в этой строчке?

Comment: движение курсора, я просто не понимаю где именно ошибка

Comment: что ты под этим понимаешь?

Comment: я просто не понимаю где double нужно преобразовать во float

Comment: у тебя проблема не в том, чтобы double преобразовать во float, а в том, что ты пытаешься `(double, double)` преобразовать во float. Посмотри что такое [кортежи](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tuples)

Comment: основная проблема в том, что в этой строке у тебя получается выражение `a = (b,c)`, а должно было быть `a = b`.

Comment: Поэтому еще раз посмотри на эту строку, и опиши что конкретно в ней происходит.

Comment: А почему `cursor` у вас представляется одним `float`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вероятно потому что float принимает функция CirclePoint :)